# Possible to have an object with both private and public fields?

Tags: security, relationships, fields

I need to be able to make records of an object Employee Private so only the owner of the record can view however I need to make the First and Last Name fields visible to all so that it can be exposed for a lookup field on another object (Company) needed to be used by anyone.

If I just set it to private, no one can lookup and select others. If I try to set field security the required fields are locked on as well as with the permission set method of just opening up those fields for that object. Those locked up fields contain information that cannot be public such as email address, etc.

Is there a way to accommodate all of that sans-code? (I was thinking a workflow web of things to accomplish this however this wouldn't be dynamically linked only plain text pasting essentially)

Essentially I want a couple fields of the employee object public and the rest private (despite being a mix of required and not).

Thank you for any input in advance,
Horatio

Comment: Is VF considered "code" for you? Even if it doesn't have any apex behind it? I can only think about a custom VF page that shows/hides sections of the page depending on the user. If you do that (and I can help with a sample) then keep in mind that the fields could be visible to others via Related Lists or Reports, so they won't be purely private.

Comment: Ya being able to get into them via other means is what I was trying to block off all together to not miss any pathways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are mixing up record level access *(OWD - Organization-Wide Sharing Defaults )* with a field level security FLS setup in *Profiles and Permission Sets*. As @masond3 indicated in his answer, you have to set OWD for `Employee` object to **Public Read Only** as you want other users to be able to select the records, but you want to have some fields to be hidden and not accessible for most of the users, so you'd have to setup a Profile (this can also be Permission Set) where assigned users would have Read rights for the fields you want them to see and then you need also to have another Profile or Permission Set with edit rights to these and other hidden fields along with ability to create/modify records for the object. Every user you want to be able to create and modify `Employee` object records would have to be assigned to this extended Profile.

Comment: The issue is that I want everyone to be able to create an employee record and CRED any records they own as well as view only one or two fields of all other employee records.

Comment: I don't think this possible without complex logic, as I could see it you might need a second object to store sensitive data

Comment: I just used a reference create/update record process to write those few fields to a new object. It doesn't link to the original and it isn't the prettiest thing but gets what I wanted done. Kind of opposite of what you were thinking (to make it easier for employees to register themselves). Thanks for the idea though

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea, but why dont you make the object read for everyone else and then create a permission set for those two fields, and then assign the permission set to all users?

Comment: Permission set are not meant to be assigned to all users. For that you would update fls at the profile using the security for the field

Comment: I don't want everyone being able to read all fields for PID reasons